# How to test pytorch GPU code on a CPU machine

Tags: unit-testing, testing, pytorch

I want to verify on CPU machine that I've moved all tensors to CUDA device correctly. Is there a way to create a mock device that is still computed on CPU but marked to be incompatible with tensors I forget to move to this device?

Motivation: this would speed up my development cycle as I don't need to deploy code and run it on the GPU server only to find out I forgot to specify device on some tensor / model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `meta` device is what you need.

```py
>>> a = torch.ones(2) # defaults to cpu
>>> b = torch.ones(2, device='meta')
>>> c = a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, meta and cpu!
```

Note that original intention for `meta` device is to compute shape and dtype of output without actually doing full computation. Tensors on `meta` device have no data in them, so I am not sure if there are some aspects of the test where meta device behaves different from a "real" device.

Interestingly I couldn't find much documentation about this meta device at all. I found it mentioned here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/61654#issuecomment-879989145